# Memory Leak when returning char *

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to convert a `const char *` as a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) and then return it, and it gives me correct output also. But `valgrind` says it has memory leak. I'm on arch linux using gcc version 11.1.0 (GCC) x64_86.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define true 0
#define false 1

char *to_set(const char *a); // fix missing prototype
char *to_set(const char *a)
{
    if (a)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(a);
        size_t cnt = 0, map_append = 0, o = 0;
        int check = false;
        char *set_char = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * len) + 1);
        strcpy(set_char, "\0");
        for (cnt = 0; cnt < len; cnt++)
        {
            check = false;
            for (o = 0; set_char[o] != '\0'; o++)
            {
                if (set_char[o] == a[cnt])
                {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (check == false)
            {
                set_char[map_append] = a[cnt];
                map_append++;
            }
        }
        return set_char;
    }
    return (char *)NULL; // else case
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] != NULL)
    {
        char *buff = to_set(argv[1]);
        printf("'%s'\n", buff);
    }
    else
        printf("no input\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Valgrind Error Message:**

```
==19499== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19499== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19499== Using Valgrind-3.17.0-07f0cdcbb4-20210319X and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19499== Command: ./main HelloWorld
==19499== Parent PID: 16246
==19499== 
--19499-- 
--19499-- Valgrind options:
--19499--    --leak-check=full
--19499--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--19499--    --track-origins=yes
--19499--    --verbose
--19499--    --log-file=valgrind-out.txt
--19499-- Contents of /proc/version:
--19499--   Linux version 5.13.13-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 11.1.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 26 Aug 2021 19:14:36 +0000
--19499-- 
--19499-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-lzcnt-rdtscp-sse3-ssse3-avx-avx2-bmi-f16c-rdrand-rdseed
--19499-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--19499-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--19499-- Reading syms from /home/tushar/Desktop/main
--19499--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--19499-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/ld-2.33.so
--19499-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--19499--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--19499-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--19499-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==19499== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-19499-by-tushar-on-???
==19499== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-19499-by-tushar-on-???
==19499== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-19499-by-tushar-on-???
==19499== 
==19499== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==19499== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==19499== or are doing some strange experiment):
==19499==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=19499 ...command...
==19499== 
==19499== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==19499==   /path/to/gdb ./main
==19499== and then give GDB the following command
==19499==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=19499
==19499== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==19499== 
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4023890 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x580bb342 (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4023660 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x580bb35c (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_index)
--19499-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--19499-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
==19499== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--19499--     old: 0x04023890 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x580bb342 vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen
--19499--     new: 0x04023890 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x048448d0 strlen
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4020070 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4845730 (strcmp)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4023df0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x48491a0 (mempcpy)
--19499-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a0b0 (libc.so.6:memmove) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
==19499== Preferring higher priority redirection:
--19499--     old: 0x049dd510 (__memcpy_avx_unalign) R-> (2018.0) 0x04846980 __memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms
--19499--     new: 0x049dd510 (__memcpy_avx_unalign) R-> (2018.1) 0x04848220 memmove
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49095b0 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a3f0 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909050 (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909610 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490b7a0 (libc.so.6:rawmemchr) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49237f0 (libc.so.6:wmemchr) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4923330 (libc.so.6:wcscmp) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a210 (libc.so.6:mempcpy) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a040 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909540 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909100 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a180 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49232f0 (libc.so.6:wcschr) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49094a0 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49091e0 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a440 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909180 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a590 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4924a40 (libc.so.6:wcsnlen) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4923370 (libc.so.6:wcscpy) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909650 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49090b0 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909460 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490fc10 (libc.so.6:memrchr) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a490 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a000 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4923440 (libc.so.6:wcslen) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4909770 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a390 (libc.so.6:stpncpy) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a330 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490b7e0 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x490a4e0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp_l) redirected to 0x48331b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49da330 (libc.so.6:__strrchr_avx2) redirected to 0x4844310 (rindex)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49da500 (libc.so.6:__strlen_avx2) redirected to 0x48447b0 (strlen)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4905320 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x483e750 (malloc)
==19499== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19499==    at 0x1091F9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==19499==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19499==    by 0x1091C9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499== 
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49da140 (libc.so.6:__strchrnul_avx2) redirected to 0x4848ca0 (strchrnul)
==19499== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19499==    at 0x48447C8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:469)
==19499==    by 0x48E6FD7: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==    by 0x48D22DE: printf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==    by 0x109092: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==19499==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19499==    by 0x1091C9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499== 
--19499-- REDIR: 0x49dd4f0 (libc.so.6:__mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x4848db0 (mempcpy)
--19499-- REDIR: 0x4905980 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4841120 (free)
==19499== 
==19499== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19499==     in use at exit: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==19499==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,035 bytes allocated
==19499== 
==19499== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==19499== Checked 94,736 bytes
==19499== 
==19499== 11 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==19499==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19499==    by 0x1091C9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499== 
==19499== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19499==    definitely lost: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==19499==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19499==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19499==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19499==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19499== 
==19499== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==19499== 
==19499== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==19499== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19499==    at 0x48447C8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:469)
==19499==    by 0x48E6FD7: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==    by 0x48D22DE: printf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==    by 0x109092: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==19499==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19499==    by 0x1091C9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499== 
==19499== 
==19499== 6 errors in context 2 of 3:
==19499== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19499==    at 0x1091F9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==19499==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19499==    by 0x1091C9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x109081: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19499==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19499== 
==19499== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./main HelloWorld
'HeloWrd'
```

**After freeing:**

```
==19709== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19709==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19709==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,035 bytes allocated
==19709== 
==19709== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19709== 
==19709== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==19709== 
==19709== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==19709== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19709==    at 0x48447C8: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:469)
==19709==    by 0x48E6FD7: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19709==    by 0x48D22DE: printf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19709==    by 0x1090A2: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19709==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==19709==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19709==    by 0x1091D9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x10908E: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19709== 
==19709== 
==19709== 6 errors in context 2 of 2:
==19709== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==19709==    at 0x109209: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x10908E: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19709==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==19709==    at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
==19709==    by 0x1091D9: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x10908E: ??? (in /home/tushar/Desktop/main)
==19709==    by 0x48A1B24: (below main) (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==19709== 
==19709== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `free(buffer);` after `printf("'%s'\n", buff);`?

Comment: But I never allocated `buff` using malloc, calloc or realloc. Then, why should I free it.

Comment: void free(void *__ptr)

Free a block allocated by malloc', realloc' or `calloc'.

File: stdlib.h

Comment: Yes you did: `char *set_char = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * len) + 1); ... return set_char;`. That's what `buff` is set to. It's pretty simple - each `malloc` should have a `free`. How many `malloc` calls are in your code and how many `free` calls  are there?

Comment: sizeof(char) is defined as 1.

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1, I know that

Comment: Also, #inlcude <stdbool.h> instead of your defines if you target a new enough version of c.

Comment: Recompile with `-g` and run `valgrind` again. The error messages will contain better information about where the leak happened.

Comment: Not related to memory leak, but your loop condition won't work: `set_char[o] != '\0'` You do not initialize `set_char` except for the first element. You should use `calloc` instead of `malloc` or `memset` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: The manual you quoted is talking about a memory block, not a specifiy variable holding the address of that block. If you assign the address to another pointer variable you still have to free it once. And only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `to_set()` you allocate memory for `set_char` which you subsequently return to caller.  The caller, in this case `main()` now has to free it to avoid the leak:

```
        char *buff = to_set(argv[1]);
        printf("'%s'\n", buff);
        free(buff);
```

Comment: If you have a different problem ask a new question.  If you do, I suggest you hard-code the input so it's easier to reproduce than an interactive program.